# Insert a .txt file into a a postgresql text field

Tags: linux, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, psql

I have the need to put automatically the content of a .txt files, containing the configuration of  web devices, into a field of a table I have defined text type.
I searched on the WEB and I found the following solution:

```
psql -U user -d mydb
\set config = `cat path_to_file/filename`
UPDATE "public"."WebDevice"
SET "Configuration" = :'conf'
WHERE "Description" = 'A00085'
;
```

This way works well but when I try to do the same in a shell script like the following I get back an error:

```
#!/bin/sh
count=0
#
DIR_FILE=/home/fvincenti/rete/file
for i in $(ls $DIR_FILE)
 do
 PATH_FILE=$DIR_FILE/$i
 FILE=`echo $i | cut -f1 -d'.'`
 #
 psql -d mydb -U user <<EOF
  \set config = `cat $PATH_FILE`
  UPDATE "public"."WebDevice"
  SET "Configuration" = :'config'
  WHERE "Description" = '$FILE';
 EOF
 let count++
 done
exit 0
```

The error is:
    ERROR:  syntax error at or near "!"
    LINE 1: !
            ^
and it seems related to the \set instruction!

If the file contains only one line the script works well, but in my case lines are more than one, formatted according .txt.
The O.S. is linux Centos 6.0 and PostgreSQL is 9.1.

I need help, this behaviour is making me crazy!
thanks in advance.

Francesco

Comment: try running with shell verbose/trace: `set -vx` just before your call to `psql`. you can add `set +vx` to turn it off after that, if it gets to messy. It will display each block that it is going to execute (as is, no variable substitution), then lines with `+` at the front indicate actual cmd that is being run with variable substituted with values. Good luck.

Comment: Shelter, thank you very much for your suggestion. I tried it but I only get the following: + psql -d cmdbsvil -U postgres
cat $PATH_FILE
++ cat /home/fvincenti/rete/file/A00085.txt
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "!". Without other informations; this seems to confirm that the problem is with \set meta-command.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed this in your post "If the file contains only one line the script works well, but in my case lines are more than one, formatted according .txt." Hm.. I'd have to see what that looks like. AND I see you have found a work-around, so be very happy for that. +1 for plowing thru to solve your own problem!

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem changing the variable and not using the meta command \set.
below the new format of the shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
count=0
#
DIR_FILE=/home/fvincenti/rete/file
for i in $(ls $DIR_FILE)
do
PATH_FILE=$DIR_FILE/$i
FILE=`echo $i | cut -f1 -d'.'`

CONF_PARAM=`cat $PATH_FILE`

psql -d cmdbsvil -U postgres <<EOF
UPDATE "public"."WebDevice"
SET "Configuration" = '$CONF_PARAM'
WHERE "Description" = '$FILE';
EOF
let count++
done
exit 0
```

In this way it works without problems. Anyway I would like to know which could be the cause of the previous problem.